# Finding angles in an isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry

I was given the following question:

> *PQRS* is an isosceles trapezoid. If angle *TRS*= 100 degrees, angle *T*=35 degrees and *PS=TS*, find the measures of the numbered angles.
> Attached is a drawing of the diagram provided.
> [image].

I am having a lot of difficulty with this. I know that angle *PRS* will be 80 degrees because it is supplementary to angle *TRS*. But, I can’t figure out the rest. I see the relationships between the angles, etc, but I can’t figure out any of these measurements. I also don’t understand why the question provides the fact that *PS=TS*. That doesn’t seem to add anything useful. It can’t be telling me the triangles are congruent, because then angle *PRS* needs to be 100 degrees, which it is not.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, $\angle{PRS}=80°$. Take the triangle $\triangle{TRS}$: we know two angles out of three, so that $\angle{TSR}=45°$. Now take the isosceles triangle $\triangle{PTS}$: the two angles adjacent to the base $PT$ are equal to $35°$, so the third angle $\angle{PST}=110°$ and then $\angle{PSR}=65°$. This is one of the two angles adjacent to the base of an isosceles trapezoid: knowing it, you can easily complete the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $PS=TS$ provides you the information $\angle RPS=35^\circ$ and with this at hand, $\angle PSR=65^\circ$. Can you finish from here?

I have assumed that the points $P,R,T$ are collinear in accord with the figure.

Comment: Why does PSR equal 65?

Comment: @Burt From the angles of triangle $PSR$: $\angle PSR=180-80-35=65$.